# Get categories and list of items in this categories

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I trying to get list of categories and their items in the same query in Linq.
something like list of category item and List of related products.

for example list of items like:

```
Class MyClass {
Category food;
List<Product> products; //here I want to get list of products in this category
}
```

And I have table that connect between them that contains the product id and the category id.

Which query should I use for getting this result?

---

Edit: example of the tables:

Table:Products

- productId
- productName
- productDesc
- productContent

Table:ProductsCategories

- productId
- categoryId

Table: Categories

- categoryId
- categoryTitle
- categoryDesc

Answer (score 1):

There is a many-to-many relationship between Product and Category. A very convenient way to query such relationships without an explicitly coded join is:

```
from c in Categories
select new MyClass { 
    Category = c, 
    Products = c.ProductCategories.Select (pc => pc.Product).ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:  (untested)

```
var q = from pc in ProductsCategories
        from cat in Categories
        where pc.productId == cat.categoryId
        from prod in Products
        where prod.productId == pc.productId
        select new { category = cat, product = prod };
var q2 = from product in q
         group product by product.categoryId into g
         select new { categoryId = g.Key, products = g };
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to get the category id of the product without the table that connect between them. I think that join is needed but I don't find a way to do that...

Comment: If you want help joining tables, you'll need to tell us something about the tables you need help with. Show us your table schemas.

Comment: I added example of the tables. I hope this will help.